# Kaon beam decay, find momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, radiation, half-life

I don't know how I should solve this exercise:

a Kaon has a mean lifetime of 12,4ns.

The question is: What momentum should a Kaon beam have, so that after 50m 50% of the original radiant intensity is still left.

Attempt at solution: I thought I could use the equation for radioactive decay: $N(t)= N_0 e^{-\lambda t}$ where $\lambda = 1/(12,4 ns)$. In this case, t should equal the half-life which is 8,6 ns.

However the resulting speed would be: $ 50m/(8,6 ns)$ which is larger then the speed of light and would lead to nonsensical momentum.

Comment: Hi Eren. Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Did you use the [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life) between mean lifetime and half life? Did you time-dilate by γ ? Did you relate  p to v with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider special relativity in this to get your correct answer. HINT:

Take the time, $t$ to be $\frac{50}{v}$, and instead of using $12.4\times 10^{-9}$ as you mean lifetime put it into the equation as $$\frac{12.4\times 10^{-9}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$ so you end up with an equation of $$log\frac{1}{2} = -\frac{50\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}{12.4\times 10^{-9}v}$$and solve for $v$ from there. 
There might be a more effective version but this definitely gets the job done. Some nasty algebra in solving for $v$, however.

Hope this helps :)